# Datadirectory for mysql not found on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04, datadirectory

I am trying to install mysql on a virtual machine (Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit).
I carefully followed the instruction on the website:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#repo-qp-apt-install-from-source

I followed just the first part: 'Steps for a Fresh Installation of MySQL'

It went perfectly, I could start and stop mysql.

Then I jumped to the section: Postinstallation Setup and Testing
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization.html

There, already at the first step, it's speaking about a directory that I don't find. More precisely, I don't find anywhere a directory that has /bin/mysqld

/bin/mysqld is needed at point 4 in the 'Data directory initialization' section.

I installed it and removed it many times. Right now it's just removed, so I can't give more information. 
In case somebody needs more info I will gladly reinstall it as before.

Any kind of help is welcome, thanks.

Comment: I think you'll find you don't need to do this part as the installation has already created the basic files you need.  Or is there something that isn't working which your trying to do?

Comment: you're right. Apparently I don't need it. Thank you :)

Comment: I've added more stuff as an answer which